# Get jar files from Maven project

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have Maven project which contains Maven Dependencies where all jar files are located. I would like to get all jar files from Maven Dependencies (see picture). I manage to get each jar file individual by going to /.m/repositoy/xxxx/. But this way seems take long time. So I just want to get all jar file once, any help?[image]

The reason why I want those jar files because I want to create java non-Maven project with those jar files.

Comment: That's the way to get them.  It's the only way I know of.  Why would you want to create a non-Maven Java project?  Make the other project use Maven, too.

Comment: I'm really curious to know why you want to create a "non-Maven" Java project. If you could explain, I'm interested.

Comment: Because My friend has a maven project in one machines working file but the same project does not work with my machine for some reason. So, I want to run the same project using non-maven project with those jar files. @Micka%c3%abl-b

Answer (score 0):

When you build the project it generates .war file as you know.You can extract it and find all the dependent jar files at {.war}\WEB-INF\lib\

Comment: I do not have .war file. I do not use Maven web project. Where can I fine such file? @Anil Kumar Athuluri

Comment: What file it generates when you do mvn package?

Comment: It creates Spark-examples-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar. but this jar file does not contains jar files that I am looking for @Anil Kumar Athuluri

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is, go to C:\Users\<>.m2\repository (your maven directory) and search *.jar...it will list out all the jars in the window. 
Copy all the jars and paste in your directory.

Comment: There're a lot of reasons why this is not a good solution. For instance, you can have dependencies that are not related to your project. Also, you can have multiple versions of the same dependency, etc...

Comment: Here my suggestion is to reduce time instead of taking one jar at a time..here based on the search term (*.jar or blah.jar) under maven directory...it will list out the respected jars...so will go and copy the jars which are required..this is just a suggestion, It might save some time..

Comment: It is ok, but my maven dependency directory has more than 100 jar files. So, this suggestion  is still time consuming .